# Query a DynamoDB table while passing a parameter nested within a forEach() method of an array

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm scanning all items from a DynamoDB table - within a Lambda function - with `DocumentClient`. I'm then looping through each item and extracting the payload that I need. I'll use that item from the payload as a parameter with `ExpressionAttributeValues` in a new query.
Everything works dandy independently. The issue is with the use of the asynchronous function `queryItems` when nested within an array forEach() method. I getting a parsing error with the function queryItems. I can query the table when I call the function outside of the loop but how else am I going to query each item independently?
I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var paramsAll = {
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    let arr = [];
    let sequence = '';
    //scan all items in table
    docClient.scan(paramsAll, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        //handle error
      }
      else {
        //Loop through each item in the table:
        let items = (data.Items);
        items.forEach(function(Item) {
          let p = (Item.payload);
          //Extract sequence from the payload
          sequence = (p.seq);
          arr.push(sequence);
          //perform other function with this array (not listed for brevity)
        });
        //Here is where I'm having the issue:
        arr.forEach(function(Item) {
          //Pass these items as a paramater within queryItems function but getting Parsing Error: unexpected token queryItems
          const results = await queryItems(Item);
          //do something with the results...
        })
      }
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    return { error: err };
  }
};

async function queryItems(p) {
  try {
    var params = {
      TableName: 'MyTable',
      KeyConditionExpression: '#seq = :value',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': p },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#seq': 'seq' }
    };
    const data = await docClient.query(params).promise();
    return data;
  }
  catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Convert `docClient.scan` to promise style too, and use `for..loop` instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've definitely run into a similar issue. What I believe is happening is just a Javascript syntax issue, where `await`ing `queryItems` inside the synchronous function provided to `forEach` will produce an error. (Although, when running the code, I do get the specific error `"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"`, so there might be something else going on.)

I see nothing wrong with the DynamoDB queries, but hoangdv's suggestions are spot on. Specifically, I'd also suggest using the promise style for `scan`, and while a `for...loop` will definitely work, using `Promise.all` and `map` will be a lot quicker to complete all the queries. Here's how I'd modify the code:

```js
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// avoid var unless you specifically require it's hoisting behavior.
const paramsAll = {
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES" // most likely not needed, I'd review this section of the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Select
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    // unless you need to assign a new array to this variable, it is better practice to use const instead.
    const arr = [];
    // let sequence = ''; // see line 24 for why I commented this out.

    // scan all items in table.
    // Destructure Items out of the response.
    // You may also need to continue scanning with the LastEvaluatedKey depending on the size of your table, and/or your use case.
    // You'd continue scanning in a while loop, for example.
    const { Items, LastEvaluatedKey } = await docClient.scan(paramsAll).promise();

    // push the sequence to the arr. 
    // There is most likely a reason you omitted for brevity to have sequence defined above,
    // but since this example doesn't need it above, I've omitted it entirely
    Items.forEach(Item => {
      const p = Item.payload;
      arr.push(p.seq);
    });

    // use a for loop or map here instead. forEach will return undefined, which cannot be await'ed.
    // instead, map will return a new array of Promises (since the callback is async).
    // Then, you can use Promise.all to await until each Promise in the array is resolved.
    // Keep in mind, depending on how many items you are iterating through, you may run into DynamoDB's ThrottlingException.
    //    You would have to batch the queries (in other words, split the arr into pieces, and iterate over each piece), which would have to be done before using map. Then, sleep for a few milliseconds before starting on the next piece.
    //    I doubt the queries will be quick enough to cause this when using a for loop, though.
    await Promise.all(arr.map(async Item => {
      const results = await queryItems(Item);
      // do something with the results...
    }));
  }
  catch (err) {
    // Again, not sure what the use case is, but just FYI this is not a valid return value if this lambda function is intended for use with using API Gateway.
    // See here :) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-types-transforms
    return { error: err };
  }
};

// Presumably, MyTable has a partitionKey of seq, otherwise this KeyConditionExpression is invalid.
async function queryItems(p) {
  try {
    var params = {
      TableName: 'MyTable',
      KeyConditionExpression: '#seq = :value',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': p },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#seq': 'seq' }
    };
    const data = await docClient.query(params).promise();
    return data;
  }
  catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

Comment: The comment from @hoangvd led me to realize this was most likely a simple JavaScript syntax error and I had started to delete this post. Your detailed comments and explanation are extremely helpful! This works great and explains so much. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is how you await on the for loop, its best to use `Promise.all()` with a `map` to await inside of a loop:

```
    await Promise.all(arr.map(async Item => {
      const results = await queryItems(Item);
      // do something with the results...
    }));
```

However, I cannot seem to understand your logic really well.

1. You Scan a table called `MyTable`, but you do not paginate, meaning you are only getting up to 1MB worth of data.
2. With the results, you strip out the `seq` value and then once again read every item from `MyTable` this time using a `Query` and `seq` as the key?

Comment: I am feeding MQTT messages into the table, and in near real time, reading back the messages to get a correct sequence of events as MQTT order isn't preserved. Since it's being processed so quickly, I'm assuming the 1MB limit would be sufficient? Each payload has a sequence associated with it so I grab what's there (scan all) place in correct order and delete as each event is processed - where queryItems comes into play. I'm guessing there is an easier method to this madness but I haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: First if all there is no order guarantee with a Scan. Secondly, when your table exceeds 1MB your Scan will only return partial results, anything that exists after the 1MB is read will be ignored.